# Is there a better way to convert an itemidlist into a path-string than SHGetPathFromIDList()?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, visual-studio-2012, windows-shell

Microsoft supplies a class `CMFCShellTreeCtrl` for browsing the shell namespace hierarchy (essentially the same thing as the left hand side of an explorer window).

This control uses `SHGetPathFromIDList()` in order to go from an item ID list to a string representation of the current path (the selected item).

It is possible to set its current item using any string which ends up matching its internal shell hierarchy even if the objects involved are not "on the filesystem" - e.g. `\\WOLF` will select the machine WOLF under the Networking node (assuming there is a machine named WOLF on your LAN).

However, the interface responds with a blank-string when you try to obtain such a path back from the control due to its reliance on `SHGetPathFromIDList()` which won't resolve shell items that are not on the filesystem.

Does anyone know of an implementation of a better `ImprovedSHGetPathFromIDList()` that works with ITEMIDLISTs that arent' on the filesystem (such as \WOLF)?

---

I could provide my own version of `SelectPath()` and `GetItemPath()` for the shell tree control itself, implementing my own version of an ITEMIDLIST <-> string logic so that the two were fully symmetrical (i.e. I would like GetItemPath() to return the same path that was used to successfully SelectPath() previously - or for any node in the tree view).

However, this could have use elsewhere, as a generically improved round trip between pathnames and ITEMIDLISTs (after all, UNC names are a reasonably common way to express a fielsystem path!)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no pre-made function for non-filesystem items.  You would have to iterate through the `ITEMIDLIST` using `IShellFolder::GetDisplayNameOf()` on each item, specifying the `SIGDN_PARENTRELATIVEPARSING` or `SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING` flag, to build up a path string manually.

Comment: could you provide a short example, please?

Comment: @Victor I'm not at a computer right now. But in a nutshell, you will have to walk the items in the `ITEMIDLIST`. Start with the `IShellFolder` that the `ITEMIDLIST` is relative to (`SHGetDesktopFolder()` for an absolute `ITEMIDLIST`). For the first item in the list, use `IShellFolder::GetDisplayNameOf()`  to get its string, and `IShellFolder::BindToObject()` to get its `IShellFolder` interface. Then repeat for each subsequent item in the list, concatenating the strings together, until the list is exhausted.